# How do I upgrade from Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 to 1.1?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have an existing Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.x install, how do I perform an upgrade to the new 1.1 release(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, upgrading a Fabric network can be performed with the following sequence:

1. Update orderers, peers, and fabric-ca. These updates may be done in parallel.
2. Update client SDKs.
3. Enable v1.1 channel capability requirements.
4. (Optional) Update the Kafka cluster.

The details of each step in the process are described in the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading_your_network_tutorial.html).

Comment: documentation link is not exist yet

Answer (score 0):

For my development environment, I deleted 1.0.5 images(emptied bin folder) and executed the command:

[image]

Comment: This will replace your 1.0.x images, but won't automatically upgrade an existing running network.

Comment: Correct, the documentation to upgrade a network is at the link I provided.